# ¿Se puede utilizar 'molesto' en el sentido de enfermedad?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario-médico

Quiero decir: estoy molesto, me duele la cabeza.

¿Tiene sentido?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando dices "molesto" es mas como una emocion, o sea, que algo paso que sientes medio enojado, de lo que yo he escuchado y visto, no se usa para decir que sientes enfermo.

Pero si te sientes enojado porque  te duele la cabeza, esta bien, esta correcto.

Answer (score 5):

Retomando lo que  Alfredo y Chewie dijeron:
"Molesto" y "molestia" son diferentes palabras con diferentes significados.

Uno puede:

> - *estar* molesto (enojado, enfadado)
> - *sentir* una molestia (malestar, incomodidad)  o incluso
> - *ser* una molestia (cuando te vuelves un malestar para alguien)

Así que si te encuentras enfadado por el dolor, tu oración es adecuada. De otro modo sería mejor que te expresaras de manera diferente.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, pero suena un poco raro tal y como lo planteas (nada erróneo, se te entendería perfectamente, pero yo lo diría distinto). «Molestia» tiene menor grado que «dolor». Yo diría que está entre «incomodidad» y «dolor». Así que, en lugar de decir:

> Estoy molesto, me duele la cabeza.

para indicar un dolor leve de la cabeza, yo diría:

> Me duele la cabeza levemente/un poco.

O quizás:

> Tengo una molestia en la cabeza.

Comment: Pues, puedo decir en lugar del original: 'no puedo pensar más en eso, estoy molesto' ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que usualmente se dice es "me siento mal". En tu caso sería:

> Me siento mal, me duele la cabeza.